# Determine if $|x|^{\frac{1}{|y|}}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Determine if $|x|^{\frac{1}{|y|}}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

How do we determine if the function $f(x,y) = |x|^{\frac{1}{|y|}}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$?

In these sorts of scenarios one way to examine if the function is continuous at a point initially you try approaching the limiting value through a few different paths.  I'm having difficulty doing that in this case. I feel it won't be continuous at $(0,0)$, but doing it in this multivariate environment is a bit confusing. Some assistance would be appreciated. More so how should I approach this sort of problem, when it isn't a straight forward looking function?

Comment: That question makes no sense, since that function is undefined at $(0,0)$.

Comment: That is my question. Examining it with the tools I do already know it appears to me as being undefined at $(0,0)$. What I want to attempt to do was show that along different paths "approaching" $(0,0)$ the function equals two different things. For example $f(x,cx) \neq f(x,0)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Really? Surely it is 0, You can say that strictly it is not defined. But if you define the value to be 0, then you get a function which is continuous at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedants would say that the $1/|y|$ is undefined at $y=0$ and so $f(x,0)$ is undefined.

Suppose, however, that you define $f(x,0)=0$ for $|x|<1$. Then it is easy to show that $f$ is continuous on the disk $|(x,y)|<1/2$ for example.

Of course, this doesn't work for the entire plane. There is an inherent discontinuity at $(1,0)$. But it is reasonable to define missing values where doing so gives you a continuous function.

Comment: You say we can show $f$ is continuous on this small disc, but how would we do that? The second part of the question actually asked to find the $\delta$ to show continuity. With a function like this that looks extremely difficult. If we didn't have to find the $\delta$ I would've just used an argument on composition of functions.

Comment: Let's stick to the point $(0,0)$. So take any $1>\epsilon>0$. We need to find $\delta$ such that if $|(x,y|<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)|<\epsilon$. Take $\delta=\epsilon$. Then $|(x,y)|<\epsilon$ implies (1) $|x|<\epsilon$ and (2) $1/|y|>1$, so $|f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ as required.